# Cursors in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, cursor

Are cursors stored permanently in Postgres? The reason I am asking is I have the following:

```
BEGIN;
DECLARE cpc CURSOR for select * from project.car order by rego, date;
FETCH  1 IN cpc;
CLOSE cpc;
COMMIT;
```

Then I start a new transaction:

```
BEGIN;
OPEN cpc;
fetch 1 in cpc;
CLOSE cpc;
COMMIT;
```

But get the error: "ERROR: cursor "cpc" does not exist SQL state: 34000".

Is there a way to get a cursor to be persisted between transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cursors are local to a transaction and cease to exist when the transaction commits or rolls back.

You can [declare `WITH HOLD` cursors](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-declare.html) that are persistent after commit, though they remain visible only within the session that created them.